# 'field is undefined' property of object undefined in LWC but testing in JS ide it works

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript

Here's the LWC JS

```
   // console.log--> this.tableData = [{"Id":"a4X6t00000006cGEAQ","Sign__c":"No Sign","Notes__c":""}];
            picklistChanged(event) {
                event.stopPropagation();
                let dataRecieved = event.detail.data; 
                const field = dataRecieved.picklistname; // "Sign__c"
                let updateItem =  { Id: dataRecieved.context, [field]: dataRecieved.value };  
        // console.log -->{"Id":"a4X6t00000006cGEAQ","Sign__c":"Existing"}
                this.updateDataValues(updateItem);
            }
        
               updateDataValues(updateItem){
                    let copyData = [... this.tableData];
                    copyData.forEach(item => {
                        if(item.Id === updateItem.Id){
                            item[field] = updateItem[field]; // Here i get the field undefined error
                        }
                    });
```

So the code above does not work in an LWC but this code below works just fine in codepen.io

```
        let data = [{"Id":"a4X6t00000006cGEAQ","Sign__c":"No Sign","Notes__c":""}];
                let dataRecieved = { context: "a4X6t00000006cGEAQ", value: "cheeze"};
                const field = "Sign__c";
                let updateItem =  { Id: dataRecieved.context, [field]: dataRecieved.value }; 
            // console.log of updateItem = {"Id":"a4X6t00000006cGEAQ","Sign__c":"cheeze"}
somefunction(updateItem);

                function somefunction(updateItem){
                let copyData = [...data];
                copyData.forEach(item => {
                            if(item.Id === updateItem.Id){
                                item[field] = updateItem[field];
                            }
                        });
    }
```

the console.log of copyData on codepen comes out as

```
[{"Id":"a4X6t00000006cGEAQ","Sign__c":"Cheeze","Notes__c":""}];
```

So it works....

I have no idea how to resolve this, lately if i have buggy JS i'll start doing something in codepen or another web IDE but this is a hard wall.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've fallen for a common problem in JavaScript. In your LWC, the "field" property is out of scope, while in the codepen.io example, the variable `field` is in the "[closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures)" for `somefunction`. You'll want to pass `field` to the other method so you can use it:

```
        picklistChanged(event) {
            event.stopPropagation();
            let dataRecieved = event.detail.data; 
            const field = dataRecieved.picklistname; // "Sign__c"
            let updateItem =  { Id: dataRecieved.context, [field]: dataRecieved.value };  
    // console.log -->{"Id":"a4X6t00000006cGEAQ","Sign__c":"Existing"}
            this.updateDataValues(updateItem, field);
        }
    
           updateDataValues(updateItem, field){
```

Comment: that did fix it and i now see what i did wrong after looking after googling JS scope. Would you say this is a good JS resource https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS

Comment: @ensir I haven't read it myself, but I have heard of it. It seems like a decent resource to learn from.